# See if newer versions of artifacts in Gradle build exist in repository

Tags: gradle, dependencies, gradle-dependencies

For artifact dependencies used by a Gradle build, is there any way to see if newer versions of those artifacts exist in any repository used by that build?

Also, what algorithm does such a tool used to determine "newer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`gradle-versions-plugin`](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin).

The documentation also explains what is considered as a more recent or latest version.

Note also that an alternative as of Gradle 4.8 is to combine [dynamic versions](https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:declaring_dependency_with_dynamic_version) and [dependency locking](https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/userguide/dependency_locking.html).